# how to create our own custom product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layout, custompage

After successfully created my own custom theme in magento 1.9,  I have to create my own custom product page. Is it possible to create our own custom product page?

Comment: You mean change product detail page ?

Comment: no.. not change product detail page.. infact  create a product page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the base view.phtml found at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Copy the file into your custom theme at

```
app/design/frontend/{YourTheme}/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and edit it to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
but after I've done the process, what should I do.. I mean where I could find that product page?

Comment: That file is the template for all product pages.

You need to edit it in something like Adobe Dreamweaver or similar.

Comment: Thanks @andre for your reply, my question is where would I see the link of product. I mean I copy that file in my theme directory then a link or something should be appear on home page or wherever so that I could see the product page properly?

Comment: You need to create a product to view first in the Magento backend and then you can review the changes to the template file (e.g. view.phtml).

Comment: Okay I created a product from backend, now where would it be showed?